# I forgot to configure login Email id and password while install pg admin 4. how i can change after installation

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5, pgadmin-4

I am new to pgAdmin 4. I have forgot to setup of login Email id and password while install pgAdmin 4. How can I change after installation? Any one can help me?

Comment: You don't need an e-mail address and password to install pgAdmin. Perhaps you installed the database server and created a database? Let me guess: you used the installer on Windows.

Comment: No, I am using ubuntu 18.0

Comment: mutti podra....

Answer (score 15):

As my friend @Almadani and @richyen post are completely right.

But If you are working on remote host databases its best to delete that folder.Such as it may on some instance[ssh]

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/pgadmin
```

After deletion of folder. you can simply create new credentials

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

You can also check it out from the blog.
By the way the blog is from [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that since you don't remember your admin/password, you didn't do much with pgAdmin yet.  If that's the case, you can move/remove the SQLite database out of the way and restart pgAdmin:

```
rm /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4-server.db
```

or

```
mv /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4-server.db /tmp
```

When you do this, you'll be prompted for a password the next time you start up the app.

You can also dump the contents of the SQLite database before moving/removing:

```
sqlite3 /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4-server.db .dump
```

Comment: SQLite? Waddaya mean?

Comment: pgAdmin stores its info in SQLite under the hood :gasp:

Comment: Oh, last time I checked (which is admittedly some time ago) it created a password file with the credentials. Has that changed?

Comment: As of v.4 everything is now stored in a SQLite db, which some would argue is just a reincarnation and reformatting of that flat file you were referencing

Comment: Hi, This file not found in my system /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4-server.db. so still not solve this problem

Comment: Sorry about my assumptions--which OS are you using?  Is there *any* file with the name like `pgadmin.*.db`?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue on Linux Fedora 32, and it's working. I hope you find it useful for you.

```
cd /var/lib/pgadmin4/ 

[root@localhost pgadmin4]# ls

pgadmin4.db  sessions  storage

[root@localhost pgadmin4]# rm pgadmin4.db

rm: remove regular file 'pgadmin4.db'? y

[root@localhost pgadmin4]# ls

sessions  storage
```

Answer (score 1):

there is still a way to find the database `pgadmin4.db` download and open this file via `HeidiSQL` as `SQLite`, directly viewing the table is not available - you can run the query `SELECT * from user` you will see your username, and if you do not remember the password can be changed to any known (encoded) - this method helped me

Answer (score 0):

It was solved with me by removing `pgadmin4.db`, and run

```
python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
```

and restart Apache web server, pgadmin4.